# What does this `/^.*$/` regex match?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm maintaining some old code when I reached a headscratcher. I am confused by this regex pattern: `/^.*$/` (as supplied as an argument in `textFieldValidation(this,'true',/^.*$/,'',''`).

I interpret this regex as:

- /^=open pattern
- .=match a single character of any value (Except EOL)
- *=match 0 or more times
- $=match end of the line
- /=close pattern

So…I think this pattern matches everything, which means the function does nothing but waste processing cycles. Am I correct?

Comment: My programmer senses are tingling, five paramerts in a javascript function, and one of them is `'true'`. That can't be good

Comment: @NicoSantangelo: it's terrible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It matches a single line of text.

It will fail to match a multiline String, because `^` matches the begining of input, and `$` matches the end of input. If there are any new line (`\n`) or caret return (`\r`) symbols in between - it fails.

For example, `'foo'.match(/^.*$/)` returns `foo`.

But `'foo\nfoo'.match(/^.*$/)` returns `null`.

Comment: Note that it will also fail to match a string containing a '\r'.

Comment: Unless you supply an argument to the regex engine telling it to match `\n` in `.`...

Answer (score 5):

`^` "Starting at the beginning."
`.` "Matching anything..."
`*` "0 or more times"
`$` "To the end of the line."

Yep, you're right on, that matches empty or something.

And [a handy little cheat sheet.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Answer (score 5):

The regexp checks that the string doesn't contain any `\n` or `\r`. Dots do not match new-lines.

Examples:

```
/^.*$/.test("");  // => true
/^.*$/.test("aoeu");  // => true
/^.*$/.test("aoeu\n");  // => false
/^.*$/.test("\n");  // => false
/^.*$/.test("aoeu\nfoo");  // => false
/^.*$/.test("\nfoo");  // => false
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are quite correct. This regex matches any string that not contains EOL (if dotall=false) or any string (if dotall=true)

Comment: I don't think JS has dotall.

Comment: I don't know how regexp's are implemented in JS, but in other languages dotall can be enabled with /../s or passing flags to compilation function